# CTC loss Expected input_lengths to have value at most 144, but got value 174

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, loss-function, research

Can someone help me with CTC loss. I wrote a conformer model for ASR and to train encoder I need CTC loss. But when I train model I got error "Expected input_lengths to have value at most 144, but got value 174 (while checking arguments for ctc_loss_cpu)".

```
encoder = ConformerEncoder(
                      d_input=80,
                      d_model=144,
                      num_layers=3,
                      conv_kernel_size=31, 
                      dropout=0.1,
                      feed_forward_residual_factor=0.5,
                      feed_forward_expansion_factor=4,
                      num_heads=4)
char_decoder = GreedyCharacterDecoder().eval()
criterion = nn.CTCLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.AdamW(encoder.parameters(), lr=0.01)
num_steps = len(train_dataloader) * 50

lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.CosineAnnealingLR(optimizer, T_max=num_steps, eta_min=0.00001)
cerwer = CerWer()

for epoch in range(50):
    train_cer, train_wer, val_wer, val_cer = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
    train_losses = []
    encoder.train()
    #model = model.float()
    for inputs, inputs_length, targets, targets_length in tqdm(train_dataloader):
        #inputs = inputs.to(device)
        #targets = targets.to(device)
        print(inputs.shape)
        print(inputs_length.shape)
        print(targets.shape)
        print(targets_length.shape)
        outputs = torch.tensor(encoder(inputs.float()))
        print(outputs.size())
        outputs = outputs.permute(2, 0, 1)
        print(outputs.log_softmax(dim=2).shape)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss = criterion(outputs.log_softmax(dim=2), targets, inputs_length, targets_length)
        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(encoder.parameters(), 15)
        optimizer.step()
        lr_scheduler.step()
        train_losses.append(loss.item())
        _, max_probs = torch.max(outputs, 2)
        train_epoch_cer, train_epoch_wer, train_decoded_words, train_target_words = cerwer(max_probs.T.cpu().numpy(),
                                                                                           targets.cpu().numpy(),
                                                                                           inputs_length,
                                                                                           targets_length)
        train_wer += train_epoch_wer
        train_cer += train_epoch_cer
```

input shape before model is:

```
torch.Size([32, 80, 659])
```

input shape before loss function is:

```
torch.Size([144, 32, 164])
```